# Memory consumption skyrocket

Tags: go, zlib

I have a program where memory keep growing. I'm not sure if it's a memory leak or just a buffer that keep growing.

I successfully isolated the problem, but I still can't find the problem.

There is some strange behavoir: if I remove the compression part, the leak disappear.
So I assume it's there. BUT if I (only) remove the clause with chanTest in the switch, the leak disappear too.
Could someone confirm the problem and explain me why it has such behavoir?
I'm using go1.0.3

Thanks!

Here is the program: ( it compress some dummy data every 100ms )

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/zlib"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeOut := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
    chanTest := make(chan int32)

    for {       
        L: for {  // timer part
            select {
                case resp := <- chanTest: // strange clause
                    fmt.Println("received stuff", resp)
                case <-timeOut.C:
                    fmt.Println("break")
                    break L
                }
           }
        timeOut = time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)

        // compression part
        data := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
        var b bytes.Buffer
        w := zlib.NewWriter(&b)
        w.Write(data)
        w.Close()

        b.Reset()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're starting a new Ticker inside the loop without calling `.Stop()` on the original. Since the Ticker runs at an interval, you end up with multiple Tickers continuing to run at the same time.

Calling `.Stop()` to halt the previous one would *technically* work:

```
timeOut.Stop()
timeOut = time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
```

...but seems to defeat the purpose of it. Instead, just don't make new Tickers in the loop, and the original will continue to run:

```
// timeOut = time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond) // not needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It seems to do the trick. Still, I don't understand why it only leaks when I'm using ZLib. And it leaked at ~700kB/s. It seems quite a lot for a simple timer.

Comment: @user1612346: I don't really understand that part either. If I reduce the "compression part" down to just this: `var b bytes.Buffer; zlib.NewWriter(&b)` There's no leak. But if I do: `zlib.NewWriter(&b).Write([]byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7})`, we get the leak. Also happens if I scope the `b` and the `data` variables outside the loops. So it seems to have something to do with the `select` keeping the variable scope alive since the `Ticker` is still running, and the `Write` keeping hold on every slice that it gets.

Comment: ...for anyone that may be interested, here's the code reduced to a minimal example that demonstrates the leak: http://play.golang.org/p/Y0RQvg0GzT It'll run for a few seconds, then panic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fix for this issue in golang tip newer than 25-Feb-2013 (revision 1c50db40d078). If you run `hg pull; hg update` to update Go's source code and recompile your Go distribution then the memory consumption issue should disappear.

However, this alone does not make the program correct - it only fixes the unusually high memory consumption. A correct implementation needs to be calling `timeout.Stop()`.

Comment: `go version devel +c05803c8e145 Wed Feb 06 11:40:54 2013 +0400 linux/amd64` leaks.

Comment: @peterSO You are right. Go tip is better than 1.0.3, but I didn't let run the program long enough. Will try to investigate the cause of the memory leak later this day.

Comment: @peterSO Implementing precise garbage collection of channels fixes the memory leaks (although not entirely - the code needs to call `timeout.Stop()`).